# Excel VBA xlMarkerStyle not plotting

Tags: vba, excel

The following Excel VBA module is designed to change the color of various line segments based on a condition. It works great except that it will not plot the individual line markers. The problem apparently exists in each of the xlMarkerStyleCircle, MarketSize, MarkerBackgroundColor, and MarkerForegroundColor lines. I'm not sure if the problem is a related to improper object naming or improper sequencing of the object references. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Likewise, if anyone sees a more efficient way of coding the same objective, please feel free to share.

Thanks kindly...

Cheers,
John

---

```
  Sub tropical_cyclone_track_format()

  With ActiveSheet
Set r = .Range("E24:E31")
For i = 1 To .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count - 1

  If r(i) = "1" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
  If r(i) = "1" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerSize = 2
  If r(i) = "1" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "1" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "1" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
  If r(i) = "1" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border.Color = RGB(255, 255, 64)
  If r(i) = "1" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Format.Line.Transparency = 0
  If r(i) = "1" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Format.Line.Weight = 1

  If r(i) = "2" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
  If r(i) = "2" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerSize = 2
  If r(i) = "2" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "2" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "2" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
  If r(i) = "2" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border.Color = RGB(255, 153, 16)
  If r(i) = "2" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Format.Line.Transparency = 0
  If r(i) = "2" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Format.Line.Weight = 1

  If r(i) = "3" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
  If r(i) = "3" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerSize = 2
  If r(i) = "3" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "3" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "3" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
  If r(i) = "3" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border.Color = RGB(255, 3, 0)
  If r(i) = "3" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Format.Line.Transparency = 0
  If r(i) = "3" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Format.Line.Weight = 1

  If r(i) = "4" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
  If r(i) = "4" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerSize = 2
  If r(i) = "4" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "4" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "4" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
  If r(i) = "4" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border.Color = RGB(80, 0, 0)
  If r(i) = "4" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Format.Line.Transparency = 0
  If r(i) = "4" Then .Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Format.Line.Weight = 1

  Next i
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this is half an answer since it provides an explanation on why your code does not plot the individual line markers, but fails to give you the right way to do it. If you want me to take a closer look at your problem you must provide your worksheet so I can evaluate the details of your chart.

On the other hand, your code is quite repetitive and therefore inefficient.

I now discuss this 2 issues.

1. `Point` object does not have a `Border` method. This is the reason
   why your code is not working. This means you cannot write code things like:

   `.Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1).Border` 
   If you want to know what methods does `Point` object has, press F2 while on VBE. If you want to know more about objects and methods you can try [analysistabs.com](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/objects-properties-methods/) or [dummies.com](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/object-properties-and-methods-in-excel-2016-vba-pr.html) and then [excel-spreadsheet.com](http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/objecthierarchy.htm). Again, I will be able to assist you if you share your worksheet.
2. You repeat 32 times the code 
   `.Shapes("CHART3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1)`
    You can
   avoid this by declaring a variable `p` of type `Point` and assign
   its value right after the for-loop. I give you an ideia how can you achieve this, but for it to work properly, you should share your worksheet.

   ```
   Sub tropical_cyclone_track_format()

   Dim r As Range
   Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("E24:E31")

   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count - 1

   Dim p As Point
   Set p = ActiveSheet.Shapes("CHART 3").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i + 1)

   If r(i) = "1" Then
       With p

           p.MarkerSize = xlMarkerStyleCircle
           p.MarkerStyle = 2
           p.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           p.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           p.Format.Line.Transparency = 0
           p.Format.Line.Weight = 1

       End With
   End If

   If r(i) = "2" Then
       With p

           p.MarkerSize = xlMarkerStyleCircle
           p.MarkerStyle = 2
           p.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           p.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           p.Format.Line.Transparency = 0
           p.Format.Line.Weight = 1

       End With
   End If

   If r(i) = "3" Then
       With p

           p.MarkerSize = xlMarkerStyleCircle
           p.MarkerStyle = 2
           p.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           p.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           p.Format.Line.Transparency = 0
           p.Format.Line.Weight = 1

       End With
   End If

   If r(i) = "4" Then
       With p

           p.MarkerSize = xlMarkerStyleCircle
           p.MarkerStyle = 2
           p.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           p.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           p.Format.Line.Transparency = 0
           p.Format.Line.Weight = 1

       End With
   End If
   Next i

   End Sub
   ```